# Which recursion type consumes less memory in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, memory-management, tail-recursion

I am doing project in PHP. In recursion, we can use the following ways to implement the recursion. In which case memory consumption will be less?

Like,

```
1]
<?php

public function testFunction1() {
    $var = $this->testFunction2();
}

public function testFunction2() {
   if(condition) {
       $this->testFunction2();
   }
}
```

OR

2]

```
public function testFunction1() {
   do{
          $var = $this->testFunction2();
    } while($var condition);
}

public function testFunction2() {
     do something here...
     return $var;
}
```

Comment: [2] consumes less stack memory
visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948357/recursion-vs-iteration-with-regards-to-memory-usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948357/recursion-vs-iteration-with-regards-to-memory-usage